# Breaking The Caesar Cipher

Tags: java, encryption, caesar-cipher

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CaesarCipher {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);   

    System.out.println("Enter the encrypted text :"); 
String cryptedtext = input.nextLine();                
    cryptedtext = cryptedtext.toLowerCase();                
String[] array = new String[cryptedtext.length()];        
    for (int i = 97; i < 123; i++)          
    {           
        int mostFrequent = 0;       
        for (int j = 0; j < cryptedtext.length(); j++) 
        {           
            if (cryptedtext.charAt(j) == i){    
                ++mostFrequent;                 
                }       
            }           
        System.out.println((char) i + " is showing " + mostFrequent + " times ");                                                               
        } 
    } 
}
```

I am trying to break the cipher and i have to count how many times does one letter repeats it self in a word or sentence. I only need to turn the crypt word/sentence to an actual sentence in English and I really don't know how to do it. I have to write something that is encrypt and count the letters that are repeating ( so far I have done that ),but i don't actually know how to decrypt it.

Comment: You cannot without **alot** more code. How does you program know that the particular attempt results in "_an actual sentence in English_"? You need a [NLP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) library. Otherwise you are no better off than doing this on pen and paper...

Comment: well i actually don't know. The decrypt is harder i think and i am having trouble

Comment: Sorry, but you think wrong. Counting characters is one line of code. Attempting a shift is maybe another couple. Finding some way to determine whether the resulting `String` is an English sentence requires at least **all** the words in the English language and an NLP of some sort to work out whether you have gibberish or a sentence...

Comment: Still, i don't know how to do it, I have only got this far for one month.

Comment: do you only have lowercase letters? what about spaces? punctuation and numbers?

Comment: it has to be basic, I don't know if i need uppercases, special character. For the  spaces yeah I need them but can't really figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Caesar cipher encrypts the message by shifting all letters (a-z) by a known key. There are 26 characters, resulting in 26 possibilities. Brute force approach will be to scan all simplest possible keys (1-26) generating decrypted text for each. One of the decrypted texts will be readable and that will be the solution. There won't be a need to use word frequency in this case. The next step challenge will be telling the computer how to pick the solution for you.

Pseudo-code

```
key=1
while key<27
   create a string/array of all letters shifted by key
   print/store results + key
   increment key
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions is to brute force keys and return a `List` of those that output the most words in a predefined dictionary. You can find such a dictionary [here](http://quizedia.com/dictionaries/ENG_DICTIONARY.TXT).

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;


public class CeasarCipher {

    final private static char fromChar = ' '; //space character
    final private static char toChar = '~'; //~
    final private static char numOfChars = toChar - fromChar + 1;

    final private static String dictionaryFilePath = "ENG_DICTIONARY.TXT";
    private static Set<String> dictionary;

    //encrypt with shiftKey
    //decrypt with numOfChars - shiftKey
    public static char[] ceasar(char [] clearText, int shiftKey) {
        char[] cipherText = new char[clearText.length];
        for (int i=0; i < clearText.length; i++) {
            cipherText[i] = (char) (clearText[i] + shiftKey);
            if (cipherText[i] > toChar) {
                cipherText[i] -= numOfChars;
            }
        }
        return cipherText;
    }

    private static Set<String> getDictionary () {
        if (dictionary != null)
            return dictionary;
        Scanner file = null;
        try {
            file = new Scanner(new File(dictionaryFilePath));
            dictionary = new HashSet<String>();
            // For each word in the input
            while (file.hasNext()) {
                // Convert the word to lower case, trim it and insert into the set
                dictionary.add(file.next().trim().toLowerCase());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Cannot find dictionary file");
        } finally {
            file.close();
        }
        return dictionary;
    }

    //count number of words found in dictionary
    public static int evaluateMetric(String input) {
        //split String by space, punctuation
        String[] splitWords = input.split("[\\p{Punct}\\s]+");
        int match = 0;

        for (String s: splitWords) {
            if (getDictionary().contains(s)) {
                match++;
            }
        }
        return match;
    }

    //return the keys that seem to output most words than the rest
    public static List<Integer> heuristicCracker(char[] cipherText) {
        int[] matchesPerKeyArray = new int[numOfChars];
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfChars; i++) {
            char[] clear = ceasar(cipherText, numOfChars - i);
            matchesPerKeyArray[i] = evaluateMetric(String.valueOf(clear));
        }
        //find keys with most matches
        int max = Arrays.stream(matchesPerKeyArray).max().getAsInt();

        List<Integer> possibleKeys = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfChars; i++) {
            if (matchesPerKeyArray[i] == max) {
                possibleKeys.add(i);
            }
        }
        return possibleKeys;
    }

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        String a = "Please don't tell me you have a headache again!!";
        char[] res = ceasar(a.toCharArray(), 12);

        List<Integer> possibleKeys = heuristicCracker(res);
        System.out.println("--- Possible Keys/Decrypted ---");
        for (int i: possibleKeys) {
            String decrypted = String.valueOf(ceasar(res, (char) (numOfChars - i)));
            System.out.println(i + ": " + decrypted);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made this simple heuristic function to tell if an input is English plaintext or not, without having an actual word list.

It works pretty well, with all English plaintext I tested scoring higher than 800, but usually more than 1000. It has a minor flaw that one Hungarian text also scored more than 1000, with others less than 800. But it's still good for its intended purpose.

```
/** 
 * This heuristic function tells us that a decoded message is English plaintext or not
 * @param letters the percentage of letters a-z, A-Z in the text
 * @param frequency the average relative frequency of its letters
 * @param lowercase the percentage of lowercase letters among all letters
 * @param spaces the percentage of spaces in the whole text
 * @return the higher number it returns, the better the chance that the text is an English message
 */
public static int plainTextHeuristic(double letters, double frequency, double lowercase, double spaces) {
// the absence of lowercase makes it less likely that it's plaintext, although it's still possible
    final double LOWERCASE_CONST = 30; 
// the absence of spaces makes it much less likely, but still has some possibility
    final double SPACE_CONST = 1; 
    return (int) Math.round( letters * frequency * (LOWERCASE_CONST + lowercase) * (SPACE_CONST + spaces) / 1000 );
}
```

First I had to calculate the input values. To get `frequency`, I used a HashMap that associates characters with their [probability of occurence in English text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency#Relative_frequencies_of_letters_in_the_English_language).